# virtual host without subdomain on apache2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, vhosts

My .htaccess is not working well on Laravel that I need to have the certain app on document root, the only way to do this is via virtual host.

Now how do I do virtual host when I'm just on LAN since I won't have domain for that.

```
192.168.2.2/vhost1
192.168.2.2/vhost2
```

I tried the Alias but it doesn't work as DocumentRoot...